# Shell script - Send a message to a remote machine and wait the answer

Tags: shell, sockets, tcp

I would like to create a shell script that implements the following steps:

```
(1) Open a TCP socket to a remote machine
(2) Send a text file zzz.txt to the remote server
(3) Wait for an answer from the remote server (like: echo "OK")
(4) Check the answer
(5) Close connection
```

To open a connection should be good this code:

```
    fd=100
    eval exec "$fd<>/dev/tcp/"REMOTE IP"/4599"
```

Comment: What's wrong with `scp`?

Comment: This is the first time I need to do a script like this so I don't know the best way to do it. How could I use scp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `scp`:

```
scp yourFile someUser@somehost.com:/someDirectory/someFilename
```

or with an IP address and using the same login as on your local machine

```
scp yourFile 192.168.0.1:/someDirectory/someFilename
```

As with nearly all commands, you can check the exit status afterwards like this:

```
echo $?
```

and it will print "0" if the previous command worked successfully.